# Python - Dynamic Brackets around sums

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that takes a number and prints its times tables with a bracket around it, this all works fine until an answer goes into the two digits

CODE:

```
number = int(input("Input a number: "))

length_of_sum = len(str(number))
longest = len(str(number*10))
length_of_sum = length_of_sum + 12 + longest
print('+-' + '-'*(length_of_sum) + '-+')
i = 1
for i in range(10):
    print('| ',number, " X ", i, " = ",number*i, '|')
    i = i + 1

print('+-' + '-'*(length_of_sum) + '-+')
```

Output:

```
Input a number:3
+-----------------+
|  3  X  0  =  0 |
|  3  X  1  =  3 |
|  3  X  2  =  6 |
|  3  X  3  =  9 |
|  3  X  4  =  12 |
|  3  X  5  =  15 |
|  3  X  6  =  18 |
|  3  X  7  =  21 |
|  3  X  8  =  24 |
|  3  X  9  =  27 |
+-----------------+
```

As you can see it all works fine but then the border gets too big, or should I 
say the border starts off too small.

(Note: could you answer this relatively simply as I'm not THAT good in python yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can format all the numbers to n digits, where n is the number of digits in `number*10`:

```
number = int(input("Input a number: "))

length_of_sum = len(str(number))
longest = len(str(number*10))
length_of_sum = length_of_sum + 12 + longest
print('+-' + '-'*(length_of_sum) + '-+')
i = 1
m = str(longest)+'d'
for i in range(10):
    print('| ',number, " X ", i, " = ",format(number*i, m), '|')
    i = i + 1

print('+-' + '-'*(length_of_sum) + '-+')
```

Run 1:

```
Input a number:  3
+-----------------+
|  3  X  0  =   0 |
|  3  X  1  =   3 |
|  3  X  2  =   6 |
|  3  X  3  =   9 |
|  3  X  4  =  12 |
|  3  X  5  =  15 |
|  3  X  6  =  18 |
|  3  X  7  =  21 |
|  3  X  8  =  24 |
|  3  X  9  =  27 |
+-----------------+
```

Run 2:

```
Input a number:  18
+-------------------+
|  18  X  0  =    0 |
|  18  X  1  =   18 |
|  18  X  2  =   36 |
|  18  X  3  =   54 |
|  18  X  4  =   72 |
|  18  X  5  =   90 |
|  18  X  6  =  108 |
|  18  X  7  =  126 |
|  18  X  8  =  144 |
|  18  X  9  =  162 |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: the % string operator is deprecated in python 3

Comment: @Albert It's still used in Python 3.6.1, anyway, I changed `%` to `format()`.